# Zend Cycle within Partials

Tags: zend-framework, cycle, partials

Is there an alternative to using 'Cycle' when creating zebra tables in Zend. ( My version does not have Cycle helper and don't really want to have to upgrade.

Using a partial loop and need each table to put out different bg color. However the partial loop doesn't seem to act as a standard loop with no repeat

Answer (score 1):

I'd use javascript, as long as that's not crutial ;)

```
$('#table row:even').addClass('even');
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you're right, the cycle helper seems to reset for every iteration of *partialLoop()*... which would be consistent with the documentation.

I've gotten round this by using the partial loop's counter, like so:

```
<tr class="<?php print ($this->partialCounter%2) ? "odd" : "even"; ?>">
    <td>Test</td>
    <td>Test</td>
    <td>Test</td>
</tr>
```